# What would be the reasons to choose RMTP over WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, rtmp

I want to develop a video chat application, between Web browser and an Android device. As far as I know I have two prominent options, WebRTC and RMTP. I have tested out WebRTC and for Web app it was quite convenient to use, so I am inclined to use it. However, I should consider all my options, since I know little about Android development.

Do I have any reason to choose RMTP over WebRTC in the following use case:

1. Simple 1 to 1 video chat
2. Between Android application and Web browser ( just Chrome and Firefox is fine)
3. Recording and storing the call

Or neither has a clear advantage over the other in this simple case? For peer discovery I have a separate application server.

Comment: Might be useful: https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc

Comment: Recording the call may be a little bit of an issue with WebRTC. You will probably have to use a webrtc MCU(like the janus-gateway). I have an rudementary [android library that eases communication with the janus-gateway](https://github.com/Computician/janus-gateway-android) and also handles the webrtc communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 1:1 video chat, there is no reason whatsoever to use RMTP.

RMTP is good (and even that is debatable in 2015) for streaming - a case where one end is producing the content and many on the other end are consuming it.

For something bidirectional, you should just pick WebRTC - its codecs are better, its availability is better and its technology is better.